# ¿como hago un manejo de usuarios en app inventor

Tags: appinventor

Estoy creando un login en app inventor en donde son 2 usuarios: admin y cliente, mi problemas es que si se logea un admin acceda al area admin y si es cliente se vaya al area cliente. los datos son traidos desde una fusiontable

Comment: Hola ike. Si es tu primera vez en StackOverflow te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el recorrido. Para que alguien pueda ayudarte con tu problema es necesario que muestres tu código con lo que has intentado o tienes hasta ahora.

Answer (score -1):

Esta bonita tu consulta, espero ayudarte con mi aporte y todavía este a tiempo:

la tabla ya la generas en fusiontables.google con todos y sus permisos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora el diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego en codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para finalizar mis pruebas de salida en el emulador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y espero que te sirva o alguno que este por appinventor comenzando

Comment: muy genial no sabia de fusion tables...se podria dar otros usos..!!